# Differentiating HTML and XML with PHP DomDocument

Tags: php, html, xml, domdocument

Is there some way to differentiate XML from HTML with PHP DomDocument?

I looked in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and didn't find anything.

I'm looking for a function like `check($string)` that returns `'is XML'` or `'is HTML'` for each `$string`.

These [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115048/practical-difference-between-xhtml-html-and-xml) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610143/differentiating-between-xhtml-and-html-with-php-domdocument) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558502/is-html5-valid-xml) in SO didn't help me.

Comment: i don't think so! because HTML is a type of XML! so they are same!
you have to find a solution by checking code , mine type or  etc..

Comment: @CyC0der: No, HTML is not a type of XML. XHTML is, but not HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function, but you can rest assured that some `$string` is well-formed XML when [`DOMDocument::loadXML()`](http://php.net/domdocument.loadxml) returned `true` (set recover to false). A HTML document fails with that.

For HTML you can use [`DOMDocument::loadHTML()`](http://php.net/domdocument.loadhtml) to check if a document can be loaded as HTML. HTML is not as strict as XML.

Comment: Thx @hakre. It looks right but the code 
`$dom = new DOMDocument();
     $var = $dom->loadXML("<html><body>Test</body></html>");
     print_r ($var);die();`
returns 1. whats is wrong?

Comment: It should return ``bool(true)`, see here: https://eval.in/413856 - And that's fine as the string *is* well-formed XML.

Comment: Actually, you're right. I did not notice that the string is an well-formed XML. I made a test with other HTML and works like a charm returning `bool(false)`

Comment: It can be that a HTML document is well-formed XML. In that case you perhaps want to also check if the `->documentElement` field's `DOMElement::$tagName` is "`html`". Compare case-insensitive. It would be a strong signal that this is a HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/class.tidy.php) extension.
Example:

```
if( preg_match('/<html[^>]*>/', $string) ) {
{
  // ... actions for XML ...
} elseif( preg_match('/<\?xml[^?]*\?>/', $string) ) {
  // ... actions for HTML ...
} else {
  // ... actions for another ...
}
```